# alternative to npm debug

Tags: node.js, logs, debugging

[npm debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) is a stupidly popular (and rightly so) logging lib for node.

It is not restricted to log levels (yay) but instead allows you to choose a "name" for each logger instance created and then you can specify which "names" are not silent.

However, it won't work in my TypeScript TS Angular project - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724165/how-to-use-the-debug-module-with-typescript - I've tried all the solutions there and messed around but it just doesn't seem to work with TypeScript 4.

I now have to either write my own simple logger OR find an alternative lib that will work with TS4.

Anyone know of any suitable npm libs? Must work similar to the "name" approach employed by npm debug and color would be nice too. Must log to the browser (not to terminal).

Many thx.

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: npm debug does actually work (it just looks like it doesn't) - you just have to setting logging level to "Verbose" in Chrome devtools